# Invalid property value CSS rotate

Tags: html, css

I created a class and I am trying to rotate 45 degrees in CSS, but Chrome says "Invalid property value"

```css
.cr {
    background-color: #444;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 13.5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 3px;
   -o-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -o-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
       -o-ms-transform: rotate(45);
             transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="cr"></div>
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: It is working to me. What version of chrome do you have?

Comment: @MarioLopez Version 35.0.1916.153 m. The fiddle shows on my browser as if it hasn't been rotated.

Comment: Does it say exactly “invalid property value”? Chrome 35 does not support `transform`, and no browser supports the invented double-prefixed versions, but this means a problem with the property *name*, not value.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes, it did. Problem is solved, I think it's just me confused by the prefix.... I didn't even think that could be where the error is since neither the texteiditor nor the console showed a single error message...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the o-webkit.
o stands for Opera, webkit is the engine behind Chrome.

It's simply `-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);`

Same with the moz prefix.

Comment: Heads up: `-o-` is the Opera prefix

Comment: Also recent versions of chrome work without the prefix.  Safari still needs it, at least the version on Mavericks.

Comment: I see. Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 2):

Correct is

```css
/* Transform */
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
     -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
        transform:rotate(45deg);
```

Check out [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/transform) which prefixes are needed for which browsers or use a service like http://prefixmycss.com/.

On caniuse.com click "Show all" to see more than the last few versions. You probably want to keep the Opera prefixes although it's not needed in recent versions but version 12 which is still quite popular requires them.

Even better would be an automation tool like grunt but that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks, it's quite helpful.